# Talkback doesn't navigate to the view above recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

I am using Recycler view for showing list items. I have made the first view item 'GONE' and set its height to 0. Currently focus is on 2nd item (technically its a 1st item, since the actual 1st item is not there). What I observed is, if I swipe left, the talkback doesn't navigate to the item above recycler view. It gets stuck there.

Note: I have not made any attribute changes, everything is set as default.

Comment: This can be due to the properties if things outside your recycler view. Can you include a minimally functional example or a gist or something. I can't replicate.

Comment: @ChrisCM This is easily reproducible with just TextView as an item. While binding the first item only make the TextView "GONE" (its shouldn't take any space). and for other items make it "VISIBLE". Have any dummy view above recycler view, you will see that talkback doesn't navigate above recycler view.